# When does the scope of a disposable variable in a while loop end?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, scope

I have a while loop wherein I do something with a memory stream - namely passing it to other objects that fill the stream or read from it. The code looks something like this:

```
public async void CaptureImages(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        await this.camera.CaptureImage(memoryStream, ct);
        await this.storage.StoreImage(memoryStream, ct);
    }
}
```

My question is: Will `memoryStream` be disposed in every iteration or once the loop ends?

While the question [C# 8 Using Declaration Scope Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59378228/1521227) answers this topic generally, it does not explicitly answer the question about the scope of disposable variables in a while-loop.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the remark. That was a typo in the while condition...

Comment: Also unrelated: Do you have a reason to make this `async void` instead of `async Task`?

Comment: @Fidor Yes. This method runs as a background thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 8 Using Declaration Scope Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378228/c-sharp-8-using-declaration-scope-confusion)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski only partly. I was explicitly confused about the while-loop. The answers showed me however that I did not think this through enough... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986759/3094533) is correct, but I wanted to expand a little bit to explain why it's correct:

This is actually a question about [c#8 using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations):

> A using declaration is a variable declaration preceded by the using keyword. It tells the compiler that the variable being declared should be disposed at the end of the enclosing scope.

Basically, the `using` declaration is compiled as a `using` statement, that ends just before the enclosing scope ends.
In other words, your code gets translated to this:

```
while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await this.camera.CaptureImage(memoryStream, ct);
        await this.storage.StoreImage(memoryStream, ct);
    }
}
```

Now this is very clear when the `memoryStream` gets disposed - at the end of every `while` iteration.

Answer (score 6):

The memory stream will be disposed at the end of the `while` loop block, so once for every `while` loop iteration.

Answer (score 3):

This is how your code will be executed (I've simplified your method to include just the necessary part):

```
public void CaptureImages(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
        }

        finally
        {
            if (memoryStream != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)memoryStream).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the `memoryStream` will be disposed in every iteration. You can find the  intermediate steps and results of your code compilation here in [SharpLap](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBUAWATgKYCGwAlgHYDmA3MmpjgJIDyDSjAzJjOgGF0Ab2Tox6SRMlReUACyDSABwAuAVxIsAtqRrEAzgAoBpKgGNiAGyulVFAPZVcDgNbEq6c6oCUyUUiSkgDu+BRWxEbe2CwGphbWtvZOAErEAI7qhqrEwH6BQQFBxZgYAG6khOjaxNoOhACeAMqqJKTa6AC86FTEwegAsrX1za1k2kY+nNIlMwC+yAtIc0A).

Comment: The link to sharpLab is invaluable! That's a handy resource!